# Combining Collections in Directus

Tags: join, collections, relationship, one-to-many, directus

I've setup a Directus CMS project with 3 collections as follows:

1. Actors
2. Movies
3. TV Shows

I'd like to associate Movies and TV Shows with Actors in a multi-select ordered list. I've tried looking at the one-to-many relationship and some others and can't seem to figure out how to build this. Ideally I would like it to look roughly like:

- Editing Actor record John Smith
- Multi-select array (or possibly some other interface) that includes all TV Shows and Movies
- All TV Shows and Movies are shown by in multi-select by field "Title" of which both collections have
- User can check boxes for individual TV Shows or Movies and order them in the multi-select as they'd like.

Do I need an intermediary junction collection? Am I missing something obvious here?

From initial impressions Directus looks to be an awesome CMS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were on the right track, but the relationship type you are looking for is a "many-to-many" (or M2M). This is because a movie can have many actors, and actors can be in many movies.

You can see the Directus documentation for this relationship setup here:

https://docs.directus.io/guides/relationships.html#many-to-many

You will add two junction tables, something like `actor_movies` and `actor_tv_shows`, each with a schema like this:

- `id` — The primary key of the relationship
- `actor_id` — The foreign key that holds the actor id
- `movie_id` — The foreign key that holds the movie id

Therefore, each record in these tables link an actor to a Movie or TV Show.

Comment: Hey Ben -- thanks so much for the quick response. Sounds great re the two junction tables but I take it there's no way, at this point, to have a single multi-select with both movies and TV shows in the same interface? I'm considering breaking the collections out into separate collections (something like Action Movies, Drama Movies, etc) with distinct fields and would like to avoid having an individual multi-select for each if possible.

Comment: No problem! That can be accomplished in one of two ways: you could combine the movies and TV shows into one collection... or you could wait for v9, which will support "many to any" relationships (for connections to items in different collections). V9 is likely 4-6 weeks out.

Comment: Just to make sure once again I'm not overlooking anything, there's no simple GUI way to combine the two collections into a third correct? I'd have to do that with a bit of code and the API? Or perhaps I could use a hook on both the TV and Movies collections that would essentially just replicate the parts of the records I want into a third collection for my multiselect?

Comment: In addition to that last question, from additional poking around is there any easy way to then have a dropdown that populates from the selected options in the multiselect? I saw some other posts that mentioned using dot notation to do so but I don't see any simple way to make that work when the dropdown appears to only have options for manually input KVPs. Thanks so much again for all the help guys!

Comment: There's no way to combine collections into one (eg: a view) at this time, but it's something we're planning to implement in v9.x. So for now it would have to be a custom interface or a different schema model.